# How to Move Line to Be Nearest Top of the First Line

Tags: html, css, button

I have code that display and contain 2 lines, and act like a Link.
I try to move the Second line to the nearest point at the top of the First line- but without success.

I try via `margin-bottom:20px` and `margin-bottom:-20px` ,but all it does, it covers the image with blue and not move close the Second line to the top first line.

How do i move it up?

Here's the HTML code:

```
<div class="elements-promo">
<div class="elements-promo__copy-wrapper">
<div class="elements-promo__content">

<a class="fill" href="example.com/">

<h2 class="elements-heading ">Top Ten Working Tools</h2>
<div class="elements-heading2">Best tools ever!</div>

</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS code:

```
.elements-heading2 {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.fill
{
    display: block;
    height: 90%;
    width: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
}
h2
{
  font-family: arial;
}
.elements-promo {
    background-color: #f93d66;
    background: linear-gradient(145deg, #4772d9, #5be0e0);
    border-radius: 4px;
    height: 62px;
}

.elements-promo__copy-wrapper {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 75%;
    flex: 0 0 75%;
    margin: 6px 0px;
    background-position: 100% left top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    max-height:60px;

}

@media (min-width:160px) {
    .elements-promo__copy-wrapper {
        background-image: url("//cdn.pbrd.co/images/HghWJ2p.png")
    }
}
.elements-promo .elements-heading {
    color: #fff;
    padding-top:5px;
}


.elements-promo__content {
  padding-right:15px;
  text-align:right;
}
```

Here's a Live one: [**JSfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rami7250/93gc3Lxk/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for you.

```
.elements-heading2 {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: relative;
    top: -19px;
}
```